# CommandNotFoundError error when trying to activating a conda environment in AWS SageMaker

Tags: python, anaconda, environment, amazon-sagemaker

### The Problem

I am working on an AWS SageMaker instance and simply trying to run a created conda environment `MyEnv`. However, when running

```
conda activate MyEnv
```

I am getting

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

I tried `conda init <SHELL_NAME>` with multiple suggested `SHELL_NAME` options but nothing changed. **I am still getting the same error**.

### FYI: More information

- When I run a `conda init bash` for example I get

```
no change     /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/condabin/conda
no change     /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/conda
no change     /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/conda-env
no change     /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/activate
no change     /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/deactivate
no change     /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
no change     /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
no change     /home/ec2-user/.bashrc
No action taken.
```

- When I run `conda env list` I get

```
# conda environments:
#
base                     /home/ec2-user/anaconda3
JupyterSystemEnv      *  /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv
MyEnv                    /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/MyEnv
...
```

and multiple more environments.

### Questions

1. Why can't I `activate` an environment?
2. How can I `activate` an environment?

Comment: I made it work with running `source activate` followed by `conda deactivate`.